# FFmpeg mux video use libavformat avcodec but output couldn't be played

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg

I'm trying write a app that take an input video and crop it to square video and ignore audio stream. Because bad performance if using command, I'm trying to use libavcodec and libavformat to do it. But the output isn't playable by any video player and duration is 0 although I wrote all frame. Here are my code.

```
void convert_video(char* input) {
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    int             i, videoStreamIndex;
    AVCodecContext  *pCodecCtx = NULL;
    AVCodec         *pCodec = NULL;
    AVFrame         *pFrame = NULL;
    AVFrame         *pFrameSquare = NULL;
    AVPacket        packet, outPacket;
    int             frameFinished;
    int             numBytes;
    uint8_t         *buffer = NULL;
    AVCodec         *pEncodec = NULL;
    AVFormatContext *poFormatCxt = NULL;
    MuxOutputStream    videoStream = {0}, audioStream = {0};
    int tar_w, tar_h;

    const enum AVPixelFormat pic_format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    const enum AVCodecID codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    AVDictionary    *optionsDict = NULL;
    char output[50];
    sprintf(output, "%soutput.mp4", ANDROID_SDCARD);

    // Register all formats and codecs
    av_register_all();

    // Open video file
    if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, input, NULL, NULL)!=0)
        return; // Couldn't open file
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&poFormatCxt, NULL, NULL, output);

    // Retrieve stream information
    if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL)<0)
        return; // Couldn't find stream information

    // Find the first video stream
    videoStreamIndex=-1;
    for(i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
        if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            videoStreamIndex=i;
            break;
        }
    if(videoStreamIndex==-1)
        return; // Didn't find a video stream

    // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
    pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->codec;
    tar_w = pCodecCtx->width > pCodecCtx->height ? pCodecCtx->height : pCodecCtx->width;
    tar_h = tar_w;

    // Find the decoder for the video stream
    pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
    pEncodec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);

    add_stream_mux(&videoStream, poFormatCxt, &pEncodec, codec_id, tar_w, tar_h);
    videoStream.st[0].time_base = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->time_base;
    videoStream.st[0].codec->time_base = videoStream.st[0].time_base;
    videoStream.st[0].codec->time_base.den *= videoStream.st[0].codec->ticks_per_frame;
//    add_stream(&audioStream, poFormatCxt, &)
    open_video(poFormatCxt, pEncodec, &videoStream, optionsDict);
    int ret = avio_open(&poFormatCxt->pb, output, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);

    // Open codec
    if(avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, &optionsDict) < 0)
        return; // Could not open codec

    ret = avformat_write_header(poFormatCxt, &optionsDict);
    if (ret != 0) {
        ANDROID_LOG("Died");
    }

    // Allocate video frame
    pFrame=av_frame_alloc();
    pFrame->format = videoStream.st->codec->pix_fmt;
    pFrame->width = pCodecCtx->width;
    pFrame->height = pCodecCtx->height;
    av_frame_get_buffer(pFrame, 32);

    // Allocate an AVFrame structure
    pFrameSquare=av_frame_alloc();
    if(pFrameSquare==NULL)
        return;

    // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
    numBytes=avpicture_get_size(pic_format, tar_w,
                                tar_h);
    buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

    // Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrameSquare
    // Note that pFrameSquare is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset
    // of AVPicture
    ret = avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameSquare, buffer, pic_format,
                   tar_w, tar_h);
    if (ret < 0) {
        ANDROID_LOG("Can't fill picture");
        return;
    }

    // Read frames and save first five frames to disk
    i=0;
    ret = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet);
    while(ret >= 0) {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if(packet.stream_index == videoStreamIndex) {
            // Decode video frame
//            av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet, videoStream.st->time_base, videoStream.st->codec->time_base);
            avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished,
                                  &packet);
//            while (!frameFinished) {
//                avcodec_decode_video2(videoStream.st->codec, pFrame, &frameFinished, NULL);
//            }
            ANDROID_LOG("Trying to decode frame %d with result %d", i, frameFinished);
            ret = av_picture_crop((AVPicture*) pFrameSquare, (AVPicture*) pFrame, pic_format, 0, 0);
            if (ret < 0) {
                ANDROID_LOG("Can't crop image");
            }
//            av_frame_get_best_effort_timestamp(pFrame);
//            av_rescale_q()

            if(frameFinished) {

                // Save the frame to disk
                av_init_packet(&outPacket);
//                av_packet_rescale_ts(&outPacket, videoStream.st->codec->time_base, videoStream.st->time_base);
                pFrameSquare->width = tar_w;
                pFrameSquare->height = tar_h;
                pFrameSquare->format = pic_format;
                pFrameSquare->pts = ++videoStream.next_pts;
                ret = avcodec_encode_video2(videoStream.st->codec, &outPacket, pFrameSquare, &frameFinished);

//                int count = 0;
//                while (!frameFinished && count++ < 6) {
//                    ret = avcodec_encode_video2(videoStream.st->codec, &outPacket, NULL, &frameFinished);
//                }
                if (frameFinished) {
                    ANDROID_LOG("Writing frame %d", i);
                    outPacket.stream_index = videoStreamIndex;
                    av_interleaved_write_frame(poFormatCxt, &outPacket);
                }
                av_free_packet(&outPacket);
            }
        }

        // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frameav_free_packet(&packet);
        ret = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet);
    }

    ret = av_write_trailer(poFormatCxt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        ANDROID_LOG("Couldn't write trailer");
    } else {
        ANDROID_LOG("Video convert finished");
    }

    // Free the RGB image
    av_free(buffer);
    av_free(pFrameSquare);

    // Free the YUV frame
    av_free(pFrame);

    // Close the codec
    avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);
//    avcodec_close(pEncodecCtx);

    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

    return;
}
```

Helper

```
#define STREAM_DURATION   10.0
#define STREAM_FRAME_RATE 25 /* 25 images/s */
#define STREAM_PIX_FMT    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P /* default pix_fmt */

/* Add an output stream. */
void add_stream_mux(MuxOutputStream *ost, AVFormatContext *oc,
                       AVCodec **codec,
                       enum AVCodecID codec_id, int width, int heigh)
{
    AVCodecContext *codecCtx;
    int i;
    /* find the encoder */
    *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
    if (!(*codec)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",
                avcodec_get_name(codec_id));
        exit(1);
    }
    ost->st = avformat_new_stream(oc, *codec);
    if (!ost->st) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ost->st->id = oc->nb_streams-1;
    codecCtx = ost->st->codec;
    switch ((*codec)->type) {
        case AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
            codecCtx->sample_fmt  = (*codec)->sample_fmts ?
                             (*codec)->sample_fmts[0] : AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;
            codecCtx->bit_rate    = 64000;
            codecCtx->sample_rate = 44100;
            if ((*codec)->supported_samplerates) {
                codecCtx->sample_rate = (*codec)->supported_samplerates[0];
                for (i = 0; (*codec)->supported_samplerates[i]; i++) {
                    if ((*codec)->supported_samplerates[i] == 44100)
                        codecCtx->sample_rate = 44100;
                }
            }
            codecCtx->channels        = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(codecCtx->channel_layout);
            codecCtx->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO;
            if ((*codec)->channel_layouts) {
                codecCtx->channel_layout = (*codec)->channel_layouts[0];
                for (i = 0; (*codec)->channel_layouts[i]; i++) {
                    if ((*codec)->channel_layouts[i] == AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO)
                        codecCtx->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO;
                }
            }
            codecCtx->channels        = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(codecCtx->channel_layout);
            ost->st->time_base = (AVRational){ 1, codecCtx->sample_rate };
            break;
        case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
            codecCtx->codec_id = codec_id;
            codecCtx->bit_rate = 400000;
            /* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
            codecCtx->width    = width;
            codecCtx->height   = heigh;
            /* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
             * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
             * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
             * identical to 1. */
            ost->st->time_base = (AVRational){ 1, STREAM_FRAME_RATE };
            codecCtx->time_base       = ost->st->time_base;
            codecCtx->gop_size      = 12; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
            codecCtx->pix_fmt       = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
            if (codecCtx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO) {
                /* just for testing, we also add B frames */
                codecCtx->max_b_frames = 2;
            }
            if (codecCtx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO) {
                /* Needed to avoid using macroblocks in which some coeffs overflow.
                 * This does not happen with normal video, it just happens here as
                 * the motion of the chroma plane does not match the luma plane. */
                codecCtx->mb_decision = 2;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    /* Some formats want stream headers to be separate. */
    if (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        codecCtx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}
static void open_video(AVFormatContext *oc, AVCodec *codec, MuxOutputStream *ost, AVDictionary *opt_arg)
{
    int ret;
    AVCodecContext *c = ost->st->codec;
    AVDictionary *opt = NULL;
    av_dict_copy(&opt, opt_arg, 0);
    /* open the codec */
    ret = avcodec_open2(c, codec, &opt);
    av_dict_free(&opt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open video codec: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }
    /* allocate and init a re-usable frame */
    ost->frame = alloc_picture(c->pix_fmt, c->width, c->height);
    if (!ost->frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* If the output format is not YUV420P, then a temporary YUV420P
     * picture is needed too. It is then converted to the required
     * output format. */
    ost->tmp_frame = NULL;
    if (c->pix_fmt != AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P) {
        ost->tmp_frame = alloc_picture(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, c->width, c->height);
        if (!ost->tmp_frame) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate temporary picture\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm afraid that I set wrong pts or time_base of frame, and also when decoding or encoding, I see that some first frame is lost, frameFinished is 0. See a post that I've to flush decoder by `avcodec_decode_video2(videoStream.st->codec, pFrame, &frameFinished, NULL)` but after try a few times, frameFinished still is 0, and with `avcodec_encode_video2(videoStream.st->codec, &outPacket, NULL, &frameFinished)` will throw error in next encode frame. So how I can get all frame that lost? I'm using FFmpeg version 3.0.1

Comment: I'm highly appreciate that if have any example that decode video and re-encode this frame, may be ignoring the audio stream. Hope that any suggestion :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After set information for out packet, the video is playable

```
outPacket.pts = av_rescale_q(packet.pts,
                                             pFormatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->time_base,
                                             videoStream.st[videoStreamIndex].time_base);
                outPacket.dts = av_rescale_q(packet.dts,
                                             pFormatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->time_base,
                                             videoStream.st[videoStreamIndex].time_base);
                outPacket.duration = av_rescale_q(packet.duration,
                                                  pFormatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->time_base,
                                                  videoStream.st[videoStreamIndex].time_base);
```